# Top is not showing some processes depending on user

Tags: linux, grep, top, processes

I developed a script containing top command that is supposed to be executed by a scheduler
When i execute it by myself i obtain the expected result, but when is executed by the scheduler i'm not getting the expected result

The line of code with problem is this one

```
ESBLOGENTRY=`top -b -n 1 -c|grep " DataFlowEngine"|grep -v grep| gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'|grep ACES_KOFAX_TCM_DRS|sed 's/[ ]*$//'`
```

I'm just executing top with no interactive and full command options (-b -n 1 -c) and after that grepping and adding a timestamp

Sysadmin of the machine, executed the command doing su to root and even my same user, and sometimes the process just disappear (ESBLOGENTRY becomes empty)

User used by the scheduler is never getting an output.

Any ideas on what could be wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
ESBLOGENTRY=`top -b -n 1 -c|grep " DataFlowEngine"|grep -v grep| gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'|grep ACES_KOFAX_TCM_DRS|sed 's/[ ]*$//'`
```

assumes that the output of `top` will include at least these two string:

```
DataFlowEngine ACES_KOFAX_TCM_DRS
```

which is 34 characters.  In a quick check, `top` is showing me the command beginning in column 64.  But `top` is only showing me lines up to 80 columns.  If your environment sets `$COLUMNS` to a wider value, `top` is likely to use that value (and in a quick check, that's what happens with Debian 7).  The [**`top`** manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) says if you use a `-w` option, it will default to 512 columns, but says nothing about the default width *without* the option.

When the lines are shortened, the grep for `ACES_KOFAX_TCM_DRS` fails, making the script return an empty string.  If you use a **`-w`** option, your script should work more consistently.

Alternatively, changing the command to

```
ESBLOGENTRY=`COLUMNS=128 top -b -n 1 -c|grep " DataFlowEngine"|grep -v grep| gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'|grep ACES_KOFAX_TCM_DRS|sed 's/[ ]*$//'`
```

would set the environment for `top` (without interfering with other programs).

Comment: Thank you. I finally found the same by myself some minutes ago. But as i can see.
top is not taking the $COLUMNS variable, my version of top in redhat linux doesn't include -w and i couldn't increase with stty
Any other idea?

Comment: The manual page for `top` on CentOS6 does not mention `-w`, but `strings` shows that the variable is used (as well as a quick test).  Perhaps you are overlooking something with the variable.